# Early debugging for Linux kernel module

Tags: linux, debugging, kernel, remote-debugging

I'm currenntly trying to debug a problem with one of my Kernel modules, that cause the whole system to freeze from time to time (every about 250 iterations) during boot. Actually it's not really boot proccess, because the module is called by udev which is user-space program, but it still very stressed time and tending to deadlocks and other bad stuff.

The problem is that I can't have the logs from the module while loading, because the syslogd is still dead while the module get stuck. What I get in the syslog or messages is just few first lines of the boot process.

I have two ideas how to debaug, but I don't know how to do:

1. Netconsole. Should be very simple, but I don't know how to force it load with wanted configuration before my module.
2. USB debug cable. I configured the kernels as described [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/earlyprintk.txt), but couldn't figure aut what exactly the device number to append after `earlyprintk=dbgp` and which port is the one I need.

So if you have any experience with one of the options above, or you have any other ideas, I'll really appriciate any hints.

**Tech data:** Kernel 3.1. Ubuntu 10.10. grub2. debug cable is NetChip USB2.0 by PLX. The machine is Dell E6410 laptop.

Thank you in advance,
David